# How to get the last word of each line in a file and put it in each line of another file

Tags: java, file

I want to copy the last word of each line in a file 1 and put it in each line of the file 2.

file 1

```
x n o n
y n n o
z n n n
```

file 2

```
n, n, n, B-S
n, o, o, I-S
n, n, n, S
```

Output

```
x n o n B-S
y n n o I-S
z n n n S
```

My code

```
    File f = new File("C:\\file.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f)); 
    File f1 = new File("C:\\file1.txt");
    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1));
    String line = null; 
    String line1 = null;
    while ((line1 = reader1.readLine())!= null) { 
        String c = line1.substring(line1.lastIndexOf(" ")+1);
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(f.getName(),true);        
                    BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);            
                    bufferWritter.write(c);
                    bufferWritter.close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Asma, welcome to SO.  There are many ways this can be done.  Generally you should attempt to solve a problem by breaking it down into parts.  Part 1:  How do I read lines from a file?  Part 2:  How do I get the last word on a line?  Part three: How do I write lines to a file?  You can then ask more specific questions regarding issues you face when attempting to solve each part of the problem.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello megaflop, thank you so much. I added my code

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to know how to read and write into files i leave you a simple code to get the last word of each line in a String. Just basic split here :

```
String input1 = "x n o n\ny n n o\nz n n n";
String input2 = "n, n, n, B-S\nn, o, o, I-S\nn, n, n, S";
String[] input1Lines = input1.split("\n");
String[] input2Lines = input2.split("\n");
String result = "";

for(int i=0; i<input2Lines.length; i++) {
  String[] words = input2Lines[i].split(", ");
  String lastWord = words[words.length-1];
  result += input1Lines[i] + " " + lastWord + "\n";
}

System.out.println(result);
```